# Comparing cells pairs in a column for duplicates Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, cell, highlight, matching

**Hello,**

Appreciate your help in advance

I have used this code below to find matching values in a column.
I am looking for help to do the following:

The code below compares all cells in the column at once for matching values starting at cell B3 and going down, then highlights all matching cells. The code works fine.
But Instead, I need to check for duplicates in pairs comparing two cells at a time instead of the whole column, and also in reverse column order starting from the bottom cell in the column and going to top.

Example of match process would be:
Compare Cell B10 = B9 (highlight both if they match, If not, Move to next pair to check, B9 = B8, B8 = B7, and so on )

```
Dim rg As Range

Set rg = Range("B3", Range("B3").End(xlDown))

Dim uv As UniqueValues

Set uv = rg.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues

uv.DupeUnique = xlDuplicate

uv.Interior.Color = vbRed
```

Thanks

Comment: Dim rg As Range
Set rg = Range("F3", Range("F3").End(xlDown))
Dim uv As UniqueValues
Set uv = rg.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
uv.DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
uv.Interior.Color = vbRed

Comment: Sorry First time using Stack ... The code above works fine .. But with two problems. 1 it doesnt start from bottom to top. 2. I need to compare two cells with each other at a time, not the whole column for duplicates.

Comment: You have a better chance of getting help with your code if you paste your code into your question.

Comment: sorry first time.. Re editing the post.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your second purpose: are you saying that you only want it to identify *adjacent* duplicates?  (e.g. "ABB" is a duplicate, but "ABA" is not?)

Comment: Your code looks good now. But I'm confused by your question. It seems like you want the same result, but coded differently? Is that correct?

Comment: Having the code run from bottom to top will change the result. Also the duplicates are  number values (if I got your question correctly) for example 22000 in Cell B10 and 22000 in cell B9 would be duplicate in this case and require highlighting. The above code processes the whole column at once, Instead I need the code to go through pairs each time it runs (in a loop).

Comment: By comparing in the way you've said (B10 and B9, and then, B9 and B8), it makes no difference if you go forwards or backwards.

Comment: Do you only want to check modular pairs? I.e. check B10 and B9, and then, B8 and B7, etc. Although it would make your question make a bit more sense, it still wouldn't matter if you went forwards or backwards when comparing pairs.

Comment: The values are in ascending order and are not random, if the loop order is reversed it would show a different result which is what I need. :) Appreciate all the help. I will try what you wrote and see if I can make it work.

Comment: No actually, B10 with B9, then Also B9 with B8, and so on.

Comment: One workaround for me would be to filter and sort the column in descending order before running the code. Now I need to only compare two cells at a time.

Comment: If you sort, you won't be comparing pairs in the way you've said you need to - you'll be searching the whole column for duplicates. Might as well use the builtin conditional formatting option.

Comment: Vexen Crabtree, Could you help now with finding matching values in a pair sequence (keeping aside now the reverse order issue) instead of whole column process, and then looping through to the end row.

Comment: Vexen Crabtree, what you said is true. this is what the code above actually does now. I need to start comparing two cells a time instead.

Comment: Read my submitted answer, from 30 mins ago it compares two at a time. Also in reverse, for whatever reason you have for that.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a loop, to give you more control over what Excel is doing. Loop over your wanted range like this:

```
For Each cell In rg

Next cell
```

But to go backwards, it's harder. You'll have to get the highest and lowest row numbers in your range, and step-1 through them.

```
for a = rg_highestrow to rg_lowestRow step -1


next
```

The problem is, this doesn't know what column you're using. The .range object is going to make things complicated. So, write a method that accepts a param of which col you want to do, and what starting and ending row. Like this:

```
sub find_duplicates(byval colnumber as integer, byval startrow as integer, byval endrow as integer)


end sub
```

Then you can loop backwards, using step -1:

```
for a = endrow to startrow step -1

next
```

You'll need the logic to spot duplicates between the current cell, and the other cell. To do this, refer to the "previous cell". This means, you want to start your loop on the SECOND row, not the first. Like this:

```
for a = (endrow-1) to startrow step -1

next
```

This won't work if there's only one row in your range. So test if your range only has one row. If it only has one, a comparison is impossible, so quit. Putting it all together so far:

```
sub find_duplicates(byval colnumber as integer, byval startrow as integer, byval endrow as integer)

    if endrow-startrow<1 then exit sub 'Needs at least 2 rows to function. Exit.

    for row_a = (endrow-1) to startrow step -1   'Loop backwards using step-1, but stop short of the very last item.
        'Do the comparison of row_a and row_a+1
        if Cells(row_a,colnumber).Value = Cells(row_a+1,colnumber).Value then
            'They match. Do whatever you need to do

        end if
    next

end sub
```

You can call it like this:

```
find_duplicates(2,10,20)
```

This will search the indicated column from row 20 to row 10, comparing pairs of rows' cells for duplicate values.

Comment: I am missing something in recalling. I need to set a range beforehand :)

Answer (score 0):

This code below has worked perfectly.

the -1 in the offset formula has helped me compare current cell to previous one (as in reverse order)

```
Dim rngMyCell As Range
    Dim wsMySheet As Worksheet
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set wsMySheet = ActiveSheet

    For Each rngMyCell In wsMySheet.Range("F3:F" & wsMySheet.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        If Val(rngMyCell.Offset(-1, 0)) = Val(rngMyCell) Then
            wsMySheet.Range("F" & rngMyCell.Row & ":F" & rngMyCell.Row).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        Else
            wsMySheet.Range("F" & rngMyCell.Row & ":F" & rngMyCell.Row).Interior.Color = xlNone
        End If
    Next rngMyCell
    
    Set wsMySheet = Nothing
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```